# Confluent Cloud Kafka - Audit Log Cluster : Sink Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-cloud

For Kafka cluster hosted in Confluent Cloud, there is an Audit Log cluster that gets created. It seems to be possible to hook a Sink connector to this cluster and drain the events out from "confluent-audit-log-events" topic.

However, I am running into the below error when I run the connector to do the same.

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [connect-offsets]
```

In my connect-distributed.properties file, I have the settings as :

```
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=3
offset.storage.partitions=3
```

What extra permission/s needs to be granted so that the connector can create the required topics in the cluster? The key/secret being used in the connect-distributed.properties files is a valid key/secret that is associated to the service account for this cluster.

Also, when I run the consumer in the console using the same key (as above) , I am able to read the audit log events just fine.

Comment: This seems like a question for Confluent support rather than Stackoverflow since it's their managed system, not your own installation? In any case, you'd need to use `kafka-acls` script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's confirmed that this feature (hooking up a connector to the Audit Log cluster) is not supported at the moment in Confluent Cloud.  This feature may be available later this year at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Audit logs captured in a topic `confluent-audit-log-events` which resides in Private cluster. You can use Kafka mirror to sync the data of topic "confluent-audit-log-events" from private cluster to your own cluster and then create a sink connector for the topic in your cluster.

More about Kafka mirror: https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/architecture/geo-replication-hands-on/?utm_medium=sem&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=ch.sem_br.nonbrand_tp.prs_tgt.dsa_mt.dsa_rgn.india_lng.eng_dv.all_con.confluent-developer&utm_term=&creative=&device=c&placement=&gad=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwsvujBhAXEiwA_UXnACKT_dZoHigXc0sRx-xzHLYyql2PlFwtFoo080W-28I-PTD5RDiYtxoC81MQAvD_BwE

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

If you read https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/connectors/logging-cloud-connectors.html#view-ccloud-connector-events, the *very* first thing you see is that viewing the Audit Log events is restricted to service and user accounts that have the OrganizationAdmin RBAC role. If you don't have that then for all practical purposes the audit cluster doesn't exist for you.