# What are the different ways to get Kafka Cluster Audit log to GCP Logging?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-cloud

What are the different ways to get Kafka Cluster Audit log to GCP Logging?
Can anyone share more information on how can I achieve it?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try Replicator or MirrorMaker?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, No, I haven't tried the Replicator or MirrorMaker. I want to write the Confluent Cloud Cluster Audit log to the GCP Logging service. As I read, Replicator or MirrorMaker is used to replication of two confluent clusters only. Can you share more information? I'm talking about this _https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/access-management/audit-logging/cloud-audit-log-concepts.html_ Cluster Audit events.

Comment: They are used between Kafka clusters, not "confluent clusters". By "GCP Logging" I assumed you meant a Kafka cluster there or Pub/Sub

Comment: @OneCricketeer, Yes you're right. I meant a Kafka cluster.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67709863/confluent-cloud-kafka-audit-log-cluster-sink-connector/67724646#67724646

Comment: @RanLupovich, Thank you so much for sharing the availability of a Sink Connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have access to the necessary topic (from what I understand the Audit topic is not stored on your own cluster), to get data out of Kafka, you need a consumer. This could be in any language.

To get data into Cloud Logging, you need to use [its API](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/apis).

---

That being said, you could use any compatible pair of Kafka clients & Cloud logging clients that you would be comfortable with.

For example, you [could write](https://medium.com/hackernoon/writing-your-own-sink-connector-for-your-kafka-stack-fa7a7bc201ea) or find a Kafka Connect Sink connector that wraps the [Java Cloud Logging client](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries).

Comment: Thank you for sharing the direction. Yeah, I found [Setting Up Cloud Logging for Java](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java). Do you know any Kafka Connect Sink Connector which I can use for fetching Kafka cluster audit data?

Comment: Kafka Connect SinkTask API is a consumer itself (you provide the bootstrap servers, topics, converters (deserializers), etc). All you need to do is write the connector code for what to do with the consumed records in the `SinkTask.put()` method, as shown in the Medium post

Comment: @Cricket , seems audit logs on confluent cloud is saved on seperate cluster,  and you don't have access (at the moment) to its internal topics, read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67709863/confluent-cloud-kafka-audit-log-cluster-sink-connector/67724646#67724646

Comment: @RanLupovich, you are right. audit logs on the confluent cloud are saved on separate its internal cluster and only accessible audit topic using their Confluent Cloud CLI or Consume with java.  Do you guys know which one is the better option? Can I wait for Sink Connector or Consumer with java? If Consumer with java then is there any GitHub repo for how we can implement it? Or Is there any other way I can achieve it?

Comment: @VishalDhanani If you can consume with cloud cli, or with Java, then it'll work as I answered. Like I said, Connect Sinks and Consumers are functionally the same.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I'm trying to consuming from the topic 'confluent-audit-log-events' in the spring boot java consumer app. Do have any sample example for a reference? How can I consumer it in java?

Comment: @Vishal You do it the same as any other topic. But like we've told you already, the cluster where the topic exists is "internal", so if you don't have its bootstrap server address, you can't read from it